# Give an example of a local domain with principal maximal ideal, which is not a valuation ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization, valuation-theory

> Give an example of a local domain with principal maximal ideal, which is not a valuation ring.

If we had Noetherianness on top of it, we'd have that it's a DVR; but without it, I have no idea how to proceed. [This](https://mathoverflow.net/a/155250) might be a potential example, but I can't make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$R=\Bbb{Z}[x,x/p,x/p^2,\ldots,y,y/p,y/p^2,\ldots]$$
Then $(p)=(p,x,x/p,x/p^2,\ldots,y,y/p,y/p^2,\ldots)$ is a principal maximal ideal and the unique one of $R_{(p)}$.

In $R_{(p)}\subset \Bbb{Q}[x,y]_{(x,y)}$,

$(x)\not\subset (y)$ and $(y)\not\subset (x)$.